# How can I make the footer of a ListView stretch to fill the remaining space?

Tags: android, listview, footer

I have a ListView which can contain any number of items. When it uses less than the whole height of the screen I want to show a footer which fills the remaining space.

The footer is just a tiled image. I can't just set it as the background of the ListView or its container, because the list items are partially transparent and it must be the main background and not the footer visible through them.

Adding the footer view works fine if the footer is of a fixed height, but if the fixed height is more than the remaining height then the ListView scrolls unnecessarily.

Making the footer view fill_parent seems to have no effect, it's just invisible.

Putting the footer view into the parent layout also has no effect, because the ListView seems to fill the whole height unless it's given a fixed layout_height value.

Is this possible?

Comment: Apologies to all those who answered, I neglected to say that the ListView is inside a ListFragment, which seems to be the cause of the parent layout solutions not working. I changed it to be a normal fragment and set up the ListView explicitly, using weight now works. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: hi, i'm curious with your solution.. in which layout did you put the weight? the listview or list item view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the layout weight to one, or check out trying a merge view: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

Comment: The ListView occupies the whole parent even with another element having a weight of 1. I can't merge the footer into the ListView (AdapterView doesn't support addView) and merging it into the parent seems to have the same effect as putting it directly into the parent (fills the whole space with fill_parent, otherwise doesn't show.)

Comment: Are you creating this listview dynamically, or inflating it from a layout?

Comment: mmm...tricky...  I'll look into it when I have a sec, unless someone figures it out first.  Have you tried creating an empty listView on an inflatable layout and then proportioning the views as desired?  Then you could fill the listView with elements dynamically, but would have better control over the base layout.  It may not be possible, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: My next step unless someone has a more elegant approach, is to measure the used height of the listview and set the height of the footer (moved into the parent) to the remainder. I can't see why that wouldn't work but it's certainly not pretty.

Comment: You would need to keep track of the given screen size as it would be different per device, but I bet it would work.  That actually might be the most elegant solution here - Android views are designed in such a way to prevent direct interaction with the screen's size and make the app more generally accessible.

Comment: Fixed years later; I do care, really.

Answer (score 1):

Put the ListView inside of another layout set the expand to fill the screen.

A LinearLayout works best for this.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <ListView android:layout_height="match_parent" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" >
        ...
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This should fill the LinearLayout to the bottom of the screen.  You can use this behavior to control how your View looks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Putting a view that scrolls inside another view that scrolls, i.e., `ListView` inside `ScrollView` isn't a good idea.

Comment: I've tried this. The ListView occupies all available space if I don't give it a fixed height, even using weight (which makes sense, hence why I'm trying to make the footer approach work.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works:

- Put the two in one parent layout (for example: Linear Layout)
- For ListView: `android:layout_hight="wrap_content"`
- For footer: `android:layout_hight="fill_parent"`

Comment: The ListView seems to always use fill_parent if a fixed height isn't specified, wrap_content has no effect (which makes sense, hence why I'm trying to make the footer approach work.)