# QML: Resize ListView footer component to fill up remaining space

Tags: qt, listview, qml

For a ListView containing items so that there is some space underneath the last item I'd like to add a footer that fills up the remaining space.

A pretty good description of the use case can be found here: [How can I make the footer of a ListView stretch to fill the remaining space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918734/how-can-i-make-the-footer-of-a-listview-stretch-to-fill-the-remaining-space)

As the presented solutions are for android, I'm having a hard time to adapt it to QML. The lo-tech way - summing up the delegate heights and spacings to calculate the footer height - would probably work but feels no good...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the

```
contentWidth : real
```

properties of the list view and subtract that from the ListView height and use the resulting value as the height for your footer. E.g.:

```
ListView
{
  id: list
  height: 100
}
Rectangle
{
  anchors.bottom: list.bottom
  height: list.height - list.contentHeight
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the hint I needed. I added the Rectangle as ListView.footer (omitting the anchor), so it is scrolled with the other content.